# How to concatenate result from one query to other query

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have two queries:

- `ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb` //it will fetch pid
- `kill -SIGUSR1 pid` //it will kill process

I want to run them as single query.

I have already tried below different queries but none is working:

- `echo "$(kill -SIGUSR1 ) $(ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb)";`
- `kill -SIGUSR1 echo "$(ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb)";`
- `echo "$(kill -SIGUSR1 ) $(ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb)";`
- `kill -SIGUSR1 echo "$(ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb)";`

How can I do this to achieve single line query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this :

```
ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb | xargs kill -SIGUSR1
ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb | xargs sudo kill -SIGUSR1 # if permission issues.
```

Comment: Thanks @Pacifist but it is not working .Error: kill: sending signal to 2754 failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: Command is working for you as it is trying to kill the pid 2754 but you need to check why it's not killing that specific pid. It's may be permission issue or something different.

Comment: Thanks @Pacifist . It worked for me with sudo. Thanks a lot.  "ps aux | pgrep -f mongod_arb | xargs sudo kill -SIGUSR1"